# Cross-store In-app billing

Tags: android, in-app-billing

what would be the best way to manage the different SDKs used by the different Android marketplaces such as Google Play, Samsung Apps, Amazon Appstore, etc.

Having separate builds for each store seems like it would be difficult to manage, especially when you're publishing many versions to many stores (e.g. Lite/Premium versions). Not to mention having to learn the various different APIs.

I could see rolling my own payment processing solution, but that may be against the terms of some of the marketplaces.

Is there a library out there to make this easier, or do I have to just suck it up and do it the hard way?

Comment: The Gradle/Android build system makes this use case a little less insanity-inducing: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use http://www.onepf.org/openiab it handles a lot of markets, the api is designed around google play billing api